# Position key of path for grouped data vector map structure

Tags: clojurescript, reagent

We have some example grouped data:

```
(def grouped-data [{:id 1
                    :title "Classic music"
                    :asks [{
                       :id 1
                       :title "In which year did it sound of song of Chopin - Nocturnes, Op. 9: No. 2 in E-flat major?"
                       :answers [{:id 1 :name "1900"}
                                 {:id 2 :name "1800"}]}
                      {:id 2
                       :title "In what century did the song of Mozart - Rondò in D major, K. 485?"
                       :answers [{:id 3 :name "XI"}
                                 {:id 4 :name "XII"}]}]}

               {:id 2
               :title "Modern music"
               :asks [{
                       :id 3
                       :title "In what year was Shakira's waka waka song known?"
                       :answers [{:id 5 :name "2010"}
                                 {:id 6 :name "2009"}]}
                      {:id 4
                       :title "In what year was Backstreet Boy's 'I want it that way song' known?"
                       :answers [{:id 7 :name "1988"}
                                 {:id 8 :name "1999"}]}]}])
```

We go through the first level with the groups to show the title:

```
(defn grouped-asks [form]
  [:<>
   (doall
    (for [[pos {:keys [id
                       title
                       asks]}]
          (map-indexed vector @grouped-data)]

      [:div.pt-10 {:key id}
       [:h2 title]
       [asks-items form asks]])) ;;  0, 1 groups
   ])
```

We show the questions of each group, but I need to calculate a result to be sent based on the chosen answer `[:answers pos :result]`, for this a form with an indexed path is needed, but the index or `position` of each item is restarted since it changes group therefore it is repeat:

```
(defn asks-items [form items]
  [:<>
   (doall
    (for [[pos {:keys [id
                       title
                       answers
                       ] :as ask}]
          (map-indexed vector (:asks items))]

      (let [_ (swap! form assoc-in [:answers pos :ask] id)]
        [:div.row {:key id}
         [:h3 title]
         [answers-options-items answers]
         
         [form [:answers pos :result]   ;; [:answers pos :result]  I need the position for path
          {:label "Result"              ;; First time pos are 0 and 1 when change the next group pos was 0 and 1
           :type :number}]              ;; When the path should be: 0, 1, 2, 3
                                        ;; 
                                        ;;  I tried to create a atom counter and inc in each iteration, this not
                                        ;;  work for react. And used r/with-let, but not inc the second iteration
         
         ])))])
```

I tried to create an atom and increase it but with react it doesn't work, enters an infinite loop.

```
(def position (r/atom -1)

....
(let [_ (swap! position inc)]
   ...
   [form [:answers @position :result])
```

I also tried not to use atom, using a mutable variable using `set!`

Could there be any solution?

Comment: Not an answer to your problem, but I'd not use positions for anything here except the order on the screen and rather go with the ids.

Comment: @cfrick you're right, but I need to submit the form with the vectorized and indexed data